# Kal Vchomer logic and halacha

Tags: halacha, maseches-shabbos, talmudic-methodology

if mes mitzvah is doche avoda and avoda is doche shabbos. Kal vchomer mes mitzvah should forsure be doche shabbos.

If A being mes mitzvah, is greater than B, performing the avoda, logically since A is greater than B and B is greater than C. Logic dictates A should forsure be greater than C in this case and mes mitzvah should infact be doche shabbat!

Comment: Are you asking a question? Which one?

Comment: im asking why isnt meis mitzvah doche shabbos based on the above formula (halacha l'masseh)

Comment: maybe the concept of one thing being "doche" another isn't transitive. Not everything logical is transitive.

Comment: @DavidFeigen The kal vachomer is no good because avoda is not kal from mes mitzva in all regards. Avoda can only be done by a kohein for instance. The gemara would say that as מה לעבודה שכן פסול בזר.

Comment: Where is the exact source for avodah being docha Shabbos? If it’s a pasuk, there’s the answer, one is specifically being told to us by the Torah, and one isn’t.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is posed by the Gemara in [Sanhedrin 35A](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.35b.4?lang=bi):

> א"ל ר"ל לר' יוחנן ותהא קבורת מת מצוה דוחה שבת מק"ו ומה עבודה שדוחה שבת קבורת מת מצוה דוחה אותה מולאחותו

> The Gemara discusses a related matter: Reish Lakish said to Rabbi Yoḥanan: And the burial of a corpse with no one to bury it [met mitzva] should override Shabbat by means of an a fortiori inference: If with regard to the Temple service, which overrides Shabbat, yet the burial of a met mitzva overrides it, based on the interpretation of the term written with regard to a nazirite: “Or for his sister” (Numbers 6:7); the Gemara pauses its recounting of the question of Reish Lakish and cites a baraita that teaches this halakha.

Then on 35B:

> שבת שנידחת מפני עבודה אינו דין שתהא קבורת מת מצוה דוחה אותה

> Having cited the baraita proving that the burial of a met mitzva overrides the Temple service, Reish Lakish continues his suggestion: With regard to Shabbat, which is overridden due to the Temple service, is it not logical that the burial of a met mitzva overrides it?

> א"ל רציחה תוכיח שדוחה את העבודה ואינה דוחה את השבת

> Rabbi Yoḥanan said to him: The halakha of murder, i.e., the obligation to kill one found liable to receive court-imposed capital punishment, proves that this is not the case, as it overrides the Temple service, e.g., if the only priest present is liable to receive court-imposed capital punishment, he is taken to be killed despite this resulting in the negation of the Temple service, but it does not override Shabbat

See there for the whole sugya.

Comment: Wow! Are you in the sugya, or did that just pop up in your brain when you saw this?

Comment: @hayam when I originally saw the question, I remembered it being somewhere and figured I’d look it up when I had a chance. Then I forgot. When you brought it up again I remembered and went to look and found it.

Comment: what about giving a kohen gadol malkus erev yom kippur?

Comment: @DavidFeigen What about it?

Answer (score 1):

The Gemara ([Yevamos 7a](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.7a.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)) brings up precisely this point and refutes it:

> קְבוּרַת מֵת מִצְוָה תִּדְחֶה שַׁבָּת מִקַּל וָחוֹמֶר: וּמָה עֲבוֹדָה שֶׁהִיא דּוֹחָה שַׁבָּת — קְבוּרַת מֵת מִצְוָה דּוֹחָה אוֹתָהּ, מִ״וּלְאַחוֹתוֹ״, שַׁבָּת שֶׁנִּדְחֵת מִפְּנֵי עֲבוֹדָה — אֵינוֹ דִּין שֶׁתְּהֵא קְבוּרַת מֵת מִצְוָה דּוֹחָה אוֹתָהּ? תַּלְמוּד לוֹמַר: ״לֹא תְבַעֲרוּ״.
>
> one can claim that the burial of a met mitzva overrides Shabbat by means of the same a fortiori inference: If the Temple service overrides Shabbat, and the burial of a met mitzva overrides it... as Shabbat is overridden by the Temple service, is it not right that the burial of a met mitzva should override it? Therefore, the verse states: “You shall kindle no fire throughout your habitations on Shabbat day” (which, the Gemara has previously explained, teaches us that melachos performed outside the Beis Hamikdash don't override Shabbos even when done in performance of a mitzvah).

Answer (score 0):

Retsicha (giving someone death penalty) is tochiach that eventhough its doche avoda it's not doche Shabbos.